# XLib Window Name Problems

Tags: c++, c, xlib, xorg

since 4 days, I try to see how XLib works, and I have finally understood that.
Si I tried to make a short program wich retrieve open window's name.
For that, I created 2 functions :

```
Window *list (Display *disp, unsigned long *len) {
    Atom prop = XInternAtom(disp,"_NET_CLIENT_LIST",False), type;
    int form;
    unsigned long remain;
    unsigned char *list;

    if (XGetWindowProperty(disp,XDefaultRootWindow(disp),prop,0,1024,False,XA_WINDOW,
                &type,&form,len,&remain,&list) != Success) {
        return 0;
    }

    return (Window*)list;
}
```

So, this first function return a window object of all the windows.
Then, I created a function to retrieve the name from all those windows.

```
char *name (Display *disp, Window win) {
    Atom prop = XInternAtom(disp,"WM_NAME",False), type;
    int form;
    unsigned long remain, len;
    unsigned char *list;


    if (XGetWindowProperty(disp,win,prop,0,1024,False,XA_STRING,
                &type,&form,&len,&remain,&list) != Success) {

        return NULL;
    }

    return (char*)list;
}
```

And this function works fine, an main.c example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i;
    unsigned long len;
    XKeyEvent esend;
    Display *disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window *list;
    char *name;

        list = (Window*)list(disp,&len);
    for (i=0;i<(int)len;i++) {
        name = name(disp,list[i]);
        printf("%d :  %s \n",i,name);
        free(name);
        }
}
```

And, It works really fine, except for Skype windows it returns:

1 :  Xlib Programming Manual: Keyboard and Pointer Events - Google Chrome

2 :  Debian Web [En fonction] - Oracle VM VirtualBox

3 :  XChat: necromoine @  /  (+CSTfnst 10:2)

4 :

5 :  root@root-Laptop: ~

6 :

And, the number 4 and 6 are blank (I actually have two opened skype window).

Can you help me please.

Comment: Have you tried using the XFetchName function to obtain the window name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `WM_NAME` is not necessarily a simple string. It could be a compound text (a different type of string), which is actually the case for Skype windows. You need to use `AnyPropertyType` instead of `XA_STRING` to get the property, then format according to actual type. Look at the source of `xprops` to see how it's done.

Comment: Thank you, I just changed XA_STRING to AnyPropertyType and let the printf like before and it works really fine, I also looked to the xprop source code, but I found it a little bit complex.

Comment: It may fail if you have non-ASCII characters in the title.